# Steps to make run wordpress plugin as a stand alone program or app. (Potential stand alone application)

Tags: wordpress

I want to make this `Wordpress` plugin [`Visual Form Builder`](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/visual-form-builder/screenshots/) make it work outside the word press as a stand alone program or app.

Any one is having any idea to make this happen outside of wordpress. This plugin is not dependent much upon the wordpress data. As I've similar requirement what this plugin is doing. How can I use this plugin outside of wordpress.

Comment: basically you would need to isolate all the wp dependent functions, and delete / replace / relink them according to case . but as a side not - it is too much work. there are a lot of classes out there to do the same, and i suspect that the wordpress plugin is only an addaptation of such classes . (examples : http://freecode.com/projects/form-builder-php-class || http://www.imavex.com/php-form-builder-class/ - or use GOOGLE - form builder class )

Comment: But I want Interactive drag and drop interface.

Comment: 1 : in the demo of the EXAMPLE class there are also draggable elements . 2 : dragabble elements can be easily made with jQuery . 3 : you can search a bit on google and find also OTHER classes from the one I wrote - which have also ready made draggable form elements. but in any case , my comments are just that - comments ..